# How to access the article layout data property in middleman 4?

Tags: erb, middleman, yaml-front-matter

I am trying to migrate my blog from Middleman 4. In my index.html.erb file I have code like this:

```
<% page_articles.each_with_index do |article, i| %>
    <% if article.data.layout == 'post' %>
        <%= partial "post", :locals => { :article => article} %>
    <% elsif article.data.layout == 'micro' %>
        <%= partial "micro", :locals => { :article => article} %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This worked fine in Middleman 3 and I could use a different partial depending on the layout property defined in each post's front matter.

However, in Middleman 4 the `layout` property is no longer visible in article.data.

All other variables are there. So far the only way to make this work is to declare frontmatter like this:

```
---
layout: post
l: post
title:  "Foo"
date:   2012-10-22 15:14:01
categories: Bar
tags:
---
```

And use `article.data.l` rather than `article.data.layout`. This, however, requires that I rewrite all of the articles and seems redundant.

What is the correct way to render articles on the index page with different partials depending on the layout property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Middleman 4 the `layout` property is considered an `option` rather than `data`.

You should be able to access the value of a page's `layout` property using `article.options.layout` or maybe `article.options[:layout]`.

Comment: Great! Thank you. The second option worked with `article.options[:layout]`